# Twitter JSON API with jQuery

Tags: json, api, jquery, twitter

```
function getUsername()
            {
                var userName = document.form.screen_name.value;
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = userName;

                var apiName = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" + userName + "&callback=?";
                document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = apiName;

            $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON(apiName, function(twitter) {
                alert(twitter.name);
                $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+twitter.follwers_count+" item2="+twitter.friends_count+"</p>");
            });
            });
```

Javascript code.

```
<form method="get" action="#" name="form">
            Username: <input type="text" name="screen_name" id="username"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="getUsername()" />
        </form>
        <p>Your username is <h2 id="display"></h2></p>
        <p>Your api url is <h2 id="display2"></h2></p>
```

HTML Code

Whats wrong with this code? The alert comes back undefined.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data comes back as an array. You need to get the object at index 0:

```
function getUsername()
{
     var userName = document.form.screen_name.value;
     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = userName;

     var apiName = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" + userName + "&callback=?";
     document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = apiName;

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $.getJSON(apiName, function(twitter) {
             alert(twitter[0].name);
             $('#showdata').html("<p>item1=" + twitter[0].follwers_count + " item2=" + twitter[0].friends_count + "</p>");
         });
     });
}
```

Of course, you could always just write `twitter = twitter[0];` at the start of your function.

---

Oh, and here's your code jQuery-ified:

```
function getUsername()
{
     var userName = $('[name=screen_name]').val();
     $("#display").html(userName);

     var apiName = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" + userName + "&callback=?";
     $("#display2").html(apiName);

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $.getJSON(apiName, function(twitter) {
             alert(twitter[0].name);
             $('#showdata').html("<p>item1=" + twitter[0].follwers_count + " item2=" + twitter[0].friends_count + "</p>");
         });
     });
}
```